# Cannot implement swiping+scrolling behavior on swipe-panel with ListView on Android

Tags: android, android-listview, scroll, panel, swipe

I have a kind of swipe-panel (which moves with help of gestures like status bar in Android) and an embedded ListView in it.
The swipe-panel may be in two states:

1. Its header is at the bottom of the screen with only general
   information about its content.
2. The panel is fullscreened and a user
   sees both the header and the ListView.

Is it possible to implement the following behavior: the panel is in its 2th state, a user scrolls ListVIew with gestures, and when the ListView is scrolled to its top, next scroll makes the swipe-panel to move to its 1st state (the panel follows user's touch, which goes to the bottom of the screen)?

Similar behavior is implemented in organization's information card in Google Maps application on Android.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And the following code:

```
public class Example extends Activity implements OnScrollListener {




private ListView listview;
private View stickyText;
private View content;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);
    content = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    stickyText = findViewById(R.id.text);
    listview.setOnScrollListener(this);
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int width = size.x;
    int height = size.y;
    listview.setPadding(0, height, 0, 0);
}

@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
        int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
    stickyText.setTranslationY(Math.max(content.getHeight() - stickyText.getHeight(), view.getChildAt(1).getTop()));

}

@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

I'm not entirely sure this code will work as is (I just wrote it without really trying it out), but the basic idea is quite simple. You have a listview with padding on top which is equal to the height of your screen. You also have a Textview that overlays your listview. Depending on how much you scroll your listview you translate that textview up to the point where it reaches the top of your screen.